# convert a list in Python into number without using STR

Tags: python, list

I am new using python and I have to do a school project using it and I'm blocked. I have to convert a list of number into one number without using STR. They told us to use **10 to solve it.
For example I would like to convert the list
List=[1,2,3,4] into the number 1234

Can you please help me ?!

Comment: Please update your question with the code you have tried.

Comment: `sum(n*10**(len(List)-i)for i,n in enumerate(List,1))`

Comment: `int(''.join(map(repr, List)))`

Comment: @Epsi95 I doubt op will be able to learn anything with that.

Comment: true, :p It is just short version and Lior Elbaz explained the logic beautifully

Comment: @Epsi95 `sum(n*10**i for i,n in enumerate(List[::-1]))`

Comment: great didn't think like that

Comment: *"Questions asking for homework help [...] must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it."* -- from the [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 2):

If you think about it, numbers represented in decimal are just a digit times a power of 10 correlated to their index.

For example

1234 = 1 * 1000 + 2 * 100 + 3 * 10 + 4 * 1

or more explicitly:

1234 = 1 * 10^3 + 2 * 10^2 + 3 * 10^1 + 4 * 10^0

With that in mind - your code should probably loop over the list and add the numbers - multiplying by 10 each iteration.

Example code:

```
def list_to_integer(num_list):
    x = 0
    for num in num_list:
        x *= 10
        x += num
    return x
```